# CMIS Client JAVA - Alfresco

Tags: java, maven, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I'm starting with Alfresco. I'm following a tutorial book Alfresco CMIS, and, to make a CMIS Client JAVA I start by using the Maven Quick Start artifact: `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.my.company.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false` and this create a project with a directory structure and a java file com.my.company.app.App.java to put this code:

```
  package com.mycompany.app;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        CmisClient cmisClient = new CmisClient();
        String connectionName = "testeConn";
        Session session = cmisClient.getSession(connectionName, "admin", "admin");
    }
}
```

And configure the pom.xml with that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- Bring in the OpenCMIS library for talking to CMIS
servers -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
      <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl
      </artifactId>
      <version>0.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And in the same package of the App class, we create the file CmisClient.java with this:

```
public class CmisClient {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CmisClient.class);
    private static Map<String, Session> connections = new
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session>();
    public CmisClient() {
    }
    public Session getSession(
        String connectionName, String username, String pwd) {
        Session session = connections.get(connectionName);
        if (session == null) {
            logger.info("Not connected, creating new connection to" +
                " Alfresco with the connection id (" + connectionName +
                    ")");
// No connection to Alfresco available, create a new one
            SessionFactory sessionFactory =
            SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String,
            String>();
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, pwd);
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL,
                "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/cmis/versions/1.1/atom");
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE,
                BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.COMPRESSION, "true");
            parameters.put(SessionParameter.CACHE_TTL_OBJECTS, "0");
// If there is only one repository exposed (e.g. Alfresco),
// these lines will help detect it and its ID
            List<Repository> repositories =
            sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameters);
            Repository alfrescoRepository = null;
            if (repositories != null && repositories.size() > 0) {
                logger.info("Found (" + repositories.size() +
                    ") Alfresco repositories");
                alfrescoRepository = repositories.get(0);
                logger.info("Info about the first Alfresco repo [ID=" +
                    alfrescoRepository.getId() + "][name=" +
                    alfrescoRepository.getName() + "][CMIS ver supported=" +
                    alfrescoRepository.getCmisVersionSupported() + "]");
            } else {
                throw new CmisConnectionException(
                    "Could not connect to the Alfresco Server, " +
                    "no repository found!");
            }
// Create a new session with the Alfresco repository
            session = alfrescoRepository.createSession();
// Save connection for reuse
            connections.put(connectionName, session);
        } else {
            logger.info("Already connected to Alfresco with the " +
                "connection id (" + connectionName + ")");
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run the command `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"` to run the code, indicated by the book. But, i got the error: http://pastebin.com/kK3YvPRF

I put on the pastebin because I think that with all debug it's more easy for understand. What is my error?

EDIT: i already try to import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api in the java file, but without success... I think maven do this, but anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it! I put the project in IntelliJ IDEA and I import .jar libraries that I downloaded from here http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html and i make all imports needed.

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Repository;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.SessionParameter;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BindingType;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
```

If anyone needs, it's that, for that problem.